# Why cant I right click in desktop while stage manager is turned on in Macos Ventura?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, ventura, stage-manager

I am unable to right click on my desktop for options whenever stage manager is turned on.
Does anyone else notice this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `Desktop Items` enabled. This will show any Desktop icons and allow right-click, which of course would be needed for their management.

`System Settings | Desktop & Dock | Stage Manager | Customise | (switch on) Desktop Items`